# Как отследить утечку памяти в CodeIgniter

Tags: highload, память, php, codeigniter

Добрый день!
Имею сложный алгоритм со множественными математическими вычислениями, которые сопровождаются mysql запросами. Алгоритм по времени может выполняться порядка 1-5 минут, из-за чего 512М памяти не хватает.
О, гуру, расскажите как правильно ликвидировать эту проблему? Заранее вас благодарю

Comment: http://ppdx.ru
На самом деле, не могу конкретно описать задачу.
Проект по теории игр, который прогоняет одну игру (примитив) 10^10 раз за одно выполнение скрипта.

Comment: CI то тут при чем ? если только вы думаете что он течет на запросах...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть профилирование от самого CI, там можно посмотреть например все SQL запросы со временем выполнением! [Смотрите подробней тут.](http://cidocs.ru/213e/general/profiling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вы не предоставили алгоритм, хуже того, даже почти ничего про этот алгоритм не сказали - что он делает, как реализован, откуда вы его взяли. Из-за этого вряд ли представляется возможным сказать что-либо по существу вопроса. Возможно (и наиболее вероятно), что речь идет о криво написанном алгоритме вкупе с не менее криво написанными запросами к еще более криво спроектированной базе данных, вследствие чего выполнение получается долгим и съедает памяти больше, чем хотелось бы

Во-вторых, с чего вы взяли, что имеют место быть утечки памяти?

В-третьих, вам не кажется, что в 2013 году 512 Мб оперативной памяти, мягко говоря, маловато?

Comment: > В-третьих, вам не кажется, что в 2013 году 512 Мб оперативной памяти, мягко говоря, маловато?

Непонятна задача, возможно 512 очень много.

Answer (score 0):

[Профилирование и отладка php-приложений с помощью xhprof & FirePHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145895/)

а также,

[Инструкция по установке](https://stojg.se/blog/2011-08-27-install-xhprof-for-php5-on-centos-ubuntu-and-debian)